# nextInt() depois do terceiro inteiro

Tags: java, scanner

Dado o exemplo.csv:

```
nome;idade;10;21;32;43;54
```

Posso utilizar a classe `Scanner` para ler tal arquivo. Utilizando o método `.useDelimiter()` e me aproveitando do `;` para pegar cada valor. De forma que uso o `.next()` para o `nome` e para a `idade`. Para os outros cinco valores uso o `.nextInt()`, visto que todos eles são inteiros.

Minha dúvida: Como fazer para ignorar, por exemplo, os três primeiros valores e pegar somente os dois últimos? Continuo usando o `.nextInt()` ou existe um outro método que me auxilie nisso?

Comment: poderia usar o next sem ser int, para não converter para numérico à toa, e só não usar o valor. (pegando como string praticamente não deveria ter overhead) - De qualquer forma, o split resolve mais diretamente, como mencionado pelo @Articuno  (mas vai ter que converter pra numérico de qq forma)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar métodos da classe `Scanner` para isso, você pode utilizar `split()` nesta string, após recuperá-la do csv e pegar apenas os valores finais, que serão os dois ultimos indices do array gerado:

```
String[] str = "nome;idade;10;21;32;43;54".split(";");

System.out.println(str[str.length-1] + " - " + str[str.length-2]);
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/N8vEyb)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o .skip() passando uma expressão regular para ignorar as partes indesejadas. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("nome;idade;10;21;32;43;54").useDelimiter(";").skip("((\\w*);){5}");

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Valor: " + sc.nextInt());
    }
}
```

A expressão regular: **((\w*);){n}** irá ignorar o que vier antes do n-ésimo ponto e vírgula. Se você rodar o exemplo acima a saída será somente o que tiver depois do 3º inteiro:

Valor: 43

Valor: 54